# creditcard processing from iphone app

Tags: iphone, paypal

I have an iphone app, i need to implement payment gate way on it.customers need to purchase item using their credit card number.I have checked paypal service , but it supports paypal to paypal transactions, 
anybody knows paypal have any library for creditcard transaction from iphone?

help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: Have you tried contacting paypal? Or searching using Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it for some kind of in app purchase? As im sure that's against apples guidelines and your app will be rejected.